# Meaning of "make your cash stretch far enough"

Tags: meaning, slang, translation

I encountered the following sentence when reading the book "Algebra for young mind":

For others, however, mathematics is a daunting subject, whether it takes the form of equations on a whiteboard or the fact that, however many times you try, **you can never make your cash stretch far enough**.

I do not quite understand the line in bold. I guess it should means that 
"you can not understand the fact no matter how many times you try." Would anybody let me know if I understand correctly? Thank you!

Comment: I'd guess it means that you can't even balance your budget, which requires only simple addition and subtraction.

Comment: It means you have too much month left at the end of your money.

Comment: "to stretch money," here: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stretch+money